# Как убрать информацию о дате создания и авторе статьи?

Tags: joomla

Название статьи тоже не нужно, в общем всю эту шапку мне надо спрятать

Comment: А версия джумлы?

Comment: Версия 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Менеджер материалов->Настройки->Материалы. На этой вкладке вы можете изменить нужные вам параметры для всех материалов. Так же в самих материалах есть параметры отображения, которые вы можете настроить для каждого материала индивидуально.